# Target platform differs from running platform in Eclipse plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin and set the Target Platform to "Running Platform". However, if I press Alt-Shift-F1 on a Java project in the Eclipse instance I'm developing in it says it's an IJavaProject but if I do the same in the target Eclipse Instance it says it's an IProject. Also, code completion can't find the interface IJavaProject. It looks like the target platform is incompatible with the running platform after all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target platform defines the possible set of plugins that are available. What you are running will can be a subset of that. Have a look at your launch configuration in the plugins tab and make sure it's what you want - probably "all workspace and enabled target plugins". Also make sure in your target platform setup and you are selecting all of the plugins of the target platform.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have "all workspace and enabled target plugins" selected, and I select all plugins I currently have. Yet the Eclipse instances seem different. Even their logos and About dialogs are not the same.

Comment: Can you try creating a new target platform definition from the running platform just to make sure there is not something odd about the current definition?

Comment: I already tried that with the same effect. I want an IJavaProject and I get an IProject.

Comment: Did you go to the HElp -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details and compare the list of plugins between the two environments? That might give a clue as to what's wrong. Also, if you have installed software in your development version using p2, maybe that's not reflected in the target environment.

Comment: The list of plugins is the same but there is a difference in "Installed Software". But I found the difference... It's only an IJavaProject if I'm in the Java perspective. The default perspective in the debug instance is Resource. If I change to the Java perspective, it's what I want.

Comment: Glad you worked it out, and happy that Eclipse is working as expected ;)