# Difference between Target platform and Dependencies while developing plugins using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

Can someone please shed light on the difference between plugin dependencies for a plugin and the target platform for that particular plugin? Has it got something to do with where the plugins are located, whether in workspace or somewhere else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this post covers it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623815/target-platform-differs-from-running-platform-in-eclipse-plugin-development

Comment: Does this post talk about dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target platform is the definition of the environment you expect the plugins to run in. The dependencies is a specification of what the plugin needs. The dependencies are resolved against the target.

The target platform will typically have a lot more than what's necessary to satisfy the dependencies of one plugin, because a solution is typically composed of multiple plugins.